# Buffer equals() throws "TypeError: argument should be a Buffer" when passed a Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

Creating two buffers with webdriver.io, which does this:

```
let screenshot = new Buffer(res.value, 'base64')
```

Then running the following checks:

```
console.log('ss1 instanceof Buffer', ss1 instanceof Buffer);
console.log('ss2 instanceof Buffer', ss2 instanceof Buffer);
console.log('ss1 isBuffer', Buffer.isBuffer(ss1));
console.log('ss2 isBuffer', Buffer.isBuffer(ss2));
ss1.equals(ss2);
```

Output is

```
ss1 instanceof Buffer true
ss2 instanceof Buffer true
ss1 isBuffer true
ss2 isBuffer true
TypeError: argument should be a Buffer
  at TypeError (native)
  at Buffer.equals (buffer.js:371:18)
```

If I create two Buffers in a terminal, x.equals(y) will return a boolean, as expected.

What could be causing this?

Comment: The rest of your code that we can't see caused it.

Comment: Well, no. That's all of my code.

Comment: Turns out something up stack (chimp/webdriverio) is injecting another object into the protocol chain. So the saveScreenshot call is returning an object inheriting from Buffer, instead of a Buffer. This causes js methods to work, because they follow the chain, but native methods to fail, because they don't.